# Upgrade facebook SDK IOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, sdk

Hi i'm about to upgrade facebook sdk for my old project to version 4.14 (latest from Facebook). I have import 3 Facebook framework using cocoapods

```
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h> 
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h> 
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>
```

I'm having problem with this method

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error;
```

say expected a type

here is the method implementation. Is there any change needed? any help is much appreciate. Thanks!

```
// This method will handle ALL the session state changes in the app
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:(NSError *)error {
    // If the session was opened successfully
    if (!error && state == FBSessionStateOpen){
        NSLog(@"Session opened");
        // Show the user the logged-in UI
        [self.trackingMainViewController refreshTableView];

        [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                // Success! Include your code to handle the results here

                [ApiClient sharedInstance].fbToken = [FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData accessToken];
                [ApiClient sharedInstance].fbID = user.objectID;

                [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Please wait..." maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeClear];
                [[ApiClient sharedInstance] isFirstTime:^(id responseObject){
                    int i = [[[responseObject objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"first_timer"] intValue];

                    //New User
                    if(i == 1) {
                        self.isNewUser = true;
                        if ([self.rootViewController isSideBarVisible])
                            [self.rootViewController toggleSideBarVisiblity];

                        proceedVC = [[ProceedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
                        [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].rootViewController cPushViewController:proceedVC];

                        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                        return;
                    }
                    //Existing User
                    else {
                        [self LoginFacebook];
                    }

                }onFailure:^(NSError *error)
                 {
                     [self.rootViewController checkSignStatus];
                     [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                 }];

            } else {
                // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
            }
        }];

        return;
    }
    if (state == FBSessionStateClosed || state == FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed){
        // If the session is closed
        NSLog(@"Session closed");
        // Show the user the logged-out UI
        [self.trackingMainViewController refreshTableView];
        [self.rootViewController checkSignStatus];
    }

    // Handle errors
    if (error){
        NSLog(@"Error");
        NSString *alertText;
        NSString *alertTitle;
        // If the error requires people using an app to make an action outside of the app in order to recover
        if ([FBErrorUtility shouldNotifyUserForError:error] == YES){
            alertTitle = @"Something went wrong";
            alertText = [FBErrorUtility userMessageForError:error];
        } else {

            // If the user cancelled login, do nothing
            if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled) {
                NSLog(@"User cancelled login");

                // Handle session closures that happen outside of the app
            } else if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryAuthenticationReopenSession){
                alertTitle = @"Session Error";
                alertText = @"Your current session is no longer valid. Please log in again.";

                // Here we will handle all other errors with a generic error message.
                // We recommend you check our Handling Errors guide for more information
                // https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors/
            } else {
                //Get more error information from the error
                NSDictionary *errorInformation = [[[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey"] objectForKey:@"body"] objectForKey:@"error"];

                // Show the user an error message
                alertTitle = @"Something went wrong";
                alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please retry. \n\n If the problem persists contact us and mention this error code: %@", [errorInformation objectForKey:@"message"]];
            }
        }
        // Clear this token
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, many changes, treat it more like new usage than a migration...

Comment: so do you mean we need to rewrite all the code?

Comment: v4 is very different to v3

Comment: can we still using old version? my project cannot run. can not find for #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>